# How can I let the `range.values` fill in as an array even if I only select one cell in excel?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-api-js-client, exceljs, js-xlsx

So I have this code about getting a distance using Google API and JavaScript to an Excel file:[enter image description here][1]

```
    Office.onReady((info) => {
  if (info.host === Office.HostType.Excel) {
    document.getElementById("sideload-msg").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("app-body").style.display = "flex";
    document.getElementById("run").onclick = run;
  }
});

// Get directionsData.distance.text from taskpane.html
var jarak = localStorage.getItem("distanceValue");

// "Type in excel" code
export async function run() {
try {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
  /**
   * Insert your Excel code here
   */
  const range = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();

  // Read the range address
  range.load("address");

  // Fill in the value
  range.values = jarak;

  await context.sync();
  console.log(`The range address was ${range.address}.`);
});
} catch (error) {
console.error(error);
}
}
```

What I'd like to ask is if I change the `range.values = jarak;` to `range.values = [[jarak], [latitude], [longitude]];` (The additional parameters will be defined later).

I want the code to let me only select one cell from excel and it fills the next 2 cells (using the new `range.values` I defined here will add it to the next column). The problem is that I have to select the 3 cells in order to let the excel fills the new `range.values` which is an array if I recall the name correctly.

How can I let the `range.values` fills in as an array even if I only select one cell in excel?

The excel interface I made is like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nh3YG.png